# Is the following private message queue name valid?

Tags: msmq

```
OS:namePrefix.nameSuffix\private$\queueName
```

Will having a `.` (dot) present in the machine `name` have an issue when specifying the `queue` name?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an MSMQ issue.
MSMQ uses standard name resolution to work out the IP address of the host machine. 
If you can PING namePrefix.nameSuffix successfully, for example, then MSMQ will be able to send messages to it.

Why do you have a dot in your machine name anyway?
I wouldn't recommend it except to represent the domain name portion.

Cheers
John Breakwell